# How to make a CSS rollover image? (sprite)

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm just trying to use this little trick I saw in one of my web design magazines to make a little image rollover but I'm having just a small bit of trouble. My attempt was a terrible fail lol. I just want to see the top half (42px tall) and then the bottom half on rollover (-42px obviously)

width is also 42px. Could someone write something up to make that happen? 
image: 
http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/6568/homebi.png

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the initial (non-`:hover`) and final (`:hover`) values of `background-position`.

```
#test {
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
    background-image: url(http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/6568/homebi.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: top;  /* <-- key step #1 */
}
#test:hover {
    background-position: bottom; /* <-- key step #2 */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mTXDU/)

---

As per your comment re: wrapping the `<div>` with an anchor (`<a>`), here's what to do:

1. Swap the `<div>` out for a `<span>`. This is because valid children of anchors must be inline elements
2. But inline-displayed elements won't behave accept dimensions! So, fix this new problem with one additional CSS property: `display: inline-block` on the span.

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9B2Bn/1/)

Comment: Hey Matt that's the best implementation for a rollover that I've seen. Nice and simple. I like the 'top' and 'bottom' positioning, almost foolproof.

Comment: @Mike: thanks! I figured it's a lot clearer to **avoid** the `background: ...` shorthand. Hopefully it shows the exact minimum you need.

Comment: This is perfect. :) but the small issue here is, How would I make this a link as well

Comment: In this case it fits, but if you are using a real sprite image (more than just the two states of the same image) you cannot rely entirely on the top/bottom positioning.. a fixed pixel position imho is better for a more general approach

Comment: @Lucius: you're absolutely right, but I wanted to make it as simple and clear as possible because the OP said that previous attempts had not worked at all. Further, if you're going to use a "real" sprite image, as you say, with more than two images, then it's much more likely that you won't be creating the image and CSS by hand at all, but rather using an image+CSS generator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu {
}
.menu a {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
.menu .home {
    background: transparent url(http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/6568/homebi.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.menu .link:hover {
    background-position: 0 -42px;
}
</style>

<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" title="Home" class="link home"><span>Home</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the bare bones for an image rollover.

the css

```
.rollover{display:block; height:42px; width:42px; background:url(http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/6568/homebi.png) top;}
.rollover:hover{background-position:bottom;}
.rollover span{display:none}
```

The html

```
<a href="#" class="rollover"><span>Home</span></a>
```

The important part is the background position, which on the buttons normal state is set to 'top', when you rollover the background postion is 'bottom'.

Assuming your image which contains both button states is 84px high this will work fine.